# Galois Group of $X^3-a $ in different cases

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

I'm trying to do I solve this exercise:

> Let $K$ be a field contained in the algebraic closure of $Q$, and $a ∈ K$. Describe the splitting field and the Galois group on $K$ of the polynomial $f(X)=X^3-a$ in the following situations:
>
> a) $K$ contains a third primitive root of unity and $a$ is a cube in $K$.
>
> b) $K$ does not contain a third primitive root of unity and $a$ is a cube in $K$.
>
> c) $K$ contains a third primitive root of unity and $a$ is not a cube in $K$.
>
> d) $K$ does not contain a third primitive root and $a$ is not a cube in $K$.

The roots of $f(X)$ are $\sqrt[3]{a},\omega\sqrt[3]{a},\omega^2\sqrt[3]{a}$ with $\omega$ third primitive root of unity.

- Now, in the first point we have $\omega \in K$ and $a=b^3$ where $b\in K$ so all roots of $f(X)$ are in $K$ and so the splitting field is $K$. Assuming that my reasoning is correct, since the elements of the Galois group cause the permutation of roots of $f(x)$ and the roots contained in $K$ are three, I would say that the Galois group is $S_3$.
- In the second point with a similar reasoning, since $\omega$ is not in $K$, I found that the breaking field is $K(\omega)$ and in this case I don't know if the Galois group is trivial because permute $\omega$ with itself or if it is again $S_3$ because the splitting field still contains all the roots of $f(x)$.

Could someone help me understand?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, use MathJax also in the title. And avoid using unusual characters like ∈. Instead, use `\in`.

Comment: No, the Galois group is NOT $S_3$ in the first case: an element of a Galois group $\text{Gal}(L/K)$ is  a field homomorphism that acts as the identity on $K$ ($L$ any Galois [ = normal + separable ] extension of $K$). In particular, $\text{Gal}(K/K)=\{1\}$. So: if all the roots belong to $K$, the splitting field  is $K$, then its Galois is trivial.